# Show that there is no Lebesgue integrable function $g$ satisfying $n\chi_{(0,\frac1n]}\leqslant g$ for all $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Show that there is no Lebesgue integrable function $g$ satisfying $n\chi_{(0,\frac1n]}\leqslant g$ for all $n$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function.

I tried to reason by contradiction. Assume there is such $g$. Then, fix arbitrary $n$ and take $x=\frac1n$ so that $n\leqslant g(x)$. Since $n$ was random, we can let $n\to\infty$ and $g(x)=\infty$. *But then $g$ cannot be Lebesgue integrable.*

I sense that something is wrong with this. (The part in italics.)  For one, by the same reasoning we can "show" that $\int n\chi_{(0,\frac1n])}\,d\lambda=\infty$, when in fact it is equal to $n\lambda((0,\frac1n])=1$.

(1) Can somebody please point out what exactly is wrong with my "proof"; I know it is wrong but I cannot see where it fails.

(2) Any thoughts about how to find a correct proof will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

(1) You have $n\le g(x)$ when $x\in [0,\frac 1n]$. So the $x$'s are changing, you cannot take $n\to \infty$ while fixing $x$.

(2) Indeed you have $g(x)\ge n$ when $x\in [0,\frac 1n]$. In particular, $g(x) \ge n$ for $x\in (\frac {1}{n+1}, \frac 1n]$. So $g(x)\ge f(x)$, where $f(x) = n$ when $x\in (\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac 1n]$. Is this $f$ integtrable?

Comment: (1) Can you elaborate a bit on (1)? $x$ depends on $n$, so it is not fixed, is it? Aren't you doing the same in (2)? For (2), no, $f$ is not integrable because $\int f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$, which diverges, right?

Comment: For example, when $c >0$ is fixed, then $c> \frac 1N$ for some large $N\in \mathbb N$. So when $n\ge N$, that $g \ge n \chi_{[0,\frac 1n]}$ does not tell you anything about $g(c)$ (except only that $c\ge 0$, as the value of $n \chi_{[0,\frac 1n]}$ at $c$ is zero (not $n$). I did not take $n\to \infty$ in $(2)$, I am just chopping $[0,1]$ into intervals. (for your calculation, it seems that it should be $\frac{1}{n+1}$, but the conclusion are the same. @Ryuky

Comment: I think I know why I am confused. What is the integral $\int n\chi_{(0,1/n]}\,d\lambda$? I think it is $n\cdot\frac1n=1$, but then if I understand correctly the above implies that it is $\infty$, no?

Comment: The integral you wrote down is $=1$. But our $f$ is strictly bigger then this $n\chi_{[0,\frac 1n]}$. They are equal only on $(\frac {1}{n+1}, \frac 1n]$. @Ryuky

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be such a Lebesgue integral function. Then $g|_{[0,1]}$ is Lebesgue integral and positive so that $0 < \int_0^1 g < + \infty$. Pick any positive integer $n \ge \int_0^1 g$: then we have
$$n+1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \int_{1/(k+1)}^{1/k} k \le \int_0^1 g \le n$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi_{(0,\frac1{n}]}$ so that $\int sd\lambda=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{n}=+\infty$.

This with $s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\chi_{(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n}]}\leq g$.

Consequently $\int gd\lambda=+\infty$.

Comment: I lost you on the second line. Why does $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\chi_{(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]}$ and why is this smaller than $g$?

Comment: Let $x\in(0,1]$. Then $x\in(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ for a unique
$n$ . We have: $\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{k}]}\left(x\right)=1$ for $k=1,\dots,n$
and $\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{k}]}\left(x\right)=0$ for $k>n$. That gives
$s\left(x\right)=n$. Next to that we have $g\left(x\right)\geq n\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}\left(x\right)=n$. Notice that intervals $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n}]$ are disjoint and cover $(0,1]$.